# GitLab push to create project does not work

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to create a project using command line. So I used the information given at https://gitlab.com/help/gitlab-basics/create-project#push-to-create-a-new-project.

I did set up a new git repository, added the remote, commited something and tried to push to create a new project using this command:
`git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.com:longroad/test master`
And what did it do? The remote told me to make sure the project does exist… :D

```
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Please tell me whats my fault. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The remote told me to make sure the project does exist

This is default git message, when pushing to remote fails.

To fix your problem, you can either register (and generate if you don't have one) your ssh key on GitLab, so that push using ssh (`git@gitlab.com:longroad/test`) will be able to authenticate you.

Alternatively you could just use HTTPS protocol (`https://gitlab.com/longroad/test.git`), which will ask you for credentials each time you do want to work with the remote repository.

[More info on the topic](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html).

After you are able to successfully authenticate, you will be able to create the repository by pushing.

Comment: Please follow the first link in the question; it explains how Gitlab allows to create a repository ("project") by pushing into non-existing repository. The question is about that, not about how to create a project first and then push.

Comment: @phd how does that change anything? longroad had problem, because he was using ssh, which won't authenticate him, unless his Gitlab profile has his ssh key registered... Using what I wrote, he can authenticate... which will allow him to create repository by pushing.